# Fetch the id associated with only the given list of values

Tags: sql, database, db2

I've a simple table say

```
customerid    clientid
----------------------
4567          1
5678          1
1298          2
4567          2
5678          2
4567          3
```

I want to get the clientid with only the list of customer id so say for
customerid in (4567,5678) clientid should be 1,
cutomerid in (4567) clientid should be 3

```
SELECT clientid 
FROM customer_client 
WHERE customerid IN (4567,5678) 
GROUP BY clientid 
HAVING COUNT(customerid) = 2
```

This returns

```
clientid
---------
1
2
```

while all I want is

```
clientid
---------
1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
SELECT DISTINCT clientid
FROM customer_client
WHERE customerid IN (4567,5678) 

EXCEPT 

SELECT DISTINCT clientid
FROM customer_client
WHERE  customerid NOT IN (4567,5678)
```

Comment: No - this get's all the values. Same problem as I defined.

Comment: @Ryan Script changed.

Answer (score 1):

Move the conditions to the `having` clause.  If you have no duplicates, you can do:

```
SELECT cc.clientid
FROM customer_client cc
GROUP BY cc.clientid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cc.customerid IN (4567, 5678) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a mill Gordon.

Comment: @Ryan . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
with t (customerid, clientid) as (values
  (4567, 1)
, (5678, 1)
, (1298, 2)
, (4567, 2)
, (5678, 2)
, (4567, 3)
)
, l (customerid) as (values
--4567, 5678
--4567
4567, 5678, 1298
)
select g1.clientid
from (
  select t.clientid, count(1) cnt
  from t
  join l on l.customerid=t.customerid
  group by t.clientid
) g1
join (
  select clientid, count(1) cnt
  from t 
  group by clientid
) g2 on g1.clientid=g2.clientid and g1.cnt=g2.cnt and g1.cnt=(select count(1) from l);
```

You don't need to specify the number of customer IDs (which may vary as in the example) anywhere in the select statement along the corresponding list of IDs.
Just a list of these IDs itself.